# talend component needed for achiving expected output

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, talend

I have few input files in the below given directories:

```
Input Files:
/tmp (Folder)    
data01_data.txt    
data01_data01.txt    
data02_data.txt    
data02_data01.txt    
data03_data.txt    
data03_data01.txt    
data04_data.txt    
data04_data01.txt    
/ABC (Folder)    
CPU_data.txt    
memory_data.txt    

Folder name 
data01    
data02    
data03    
data04    
CPU
```

memory

Now I want to insert files in the folders which has name starting same as file name.

```
eg:
data01_data.txt        
data01_data01.txt
```

SO above files needs to be moved to data01 folder.I am not able to figure out the component and the way it needs to be used.
I am new in talend so unable to understand which component is need to achieve to objective.

Comment: Anyone over here please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using several components :

- tFileList to list files in a repository (here /tmp)
- Then you have to extract the first part of your filename with java code (tJava) **data01**_data.txt and put the result in a global var for example
- Then a tFileCopy, to copy your file in the repository name that you store in the global var

I hope it will help you !